# insert multiple image data into database with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem for looping data and save to database. the result of this insert data contains only one. and what is the differences in insert() with insert_batch() ? i'm sorry CTRL + K on my keyboard is not function.

my view :

```html
<?php echo form_open('proses_tambah_produk')?>
<input type="file" id="gambar2" name="gambar_tambah[]" class="form-control" style="width:90%;display:initial;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<label style="background-color:red;color:white;border-radius:50%;padding:3px;" id="idGambar2" class="hapus_gambar glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></label>
<input type="file" id="gambar2" name="gambar_tambah[]" class="form-control" style="width:90%;display:initial;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
<label style="background-color:red;color:white;border-radius:50%;padding:3px;" id="idGambar2" class="hapus_gambar glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></label>
<?php echo form_close()?>
```

my controller :

```html
function proses_tambah_produk(){
        $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/img/produk';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']             = 1000;
        $config['overwrite']             = TRUE;
        //$config['max_width']            = 1024;
        //$config['max_height']           = 768;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $files = $_FILES;
        $count = count($_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name']);
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
                {
                $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name']= $files['gambar_tambah']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['type']= $files['gambar_tambah']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['tmp_name']= $files['gambar_tambah']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['error']= $files['gambar_tambah']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['size']= $files['gambar_tambah']['size'][$i];
                $this->upload->do_upload('gambar_tambah');
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;

                }
              $fileName = $images;

            $tambahan = $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name'];

            $this->produk_adm->add($data, $gambar, $tambahan);

    }
```

my model :

```html
function add($tambahan){
        $last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $data_gambar = array(
            'id_produk' => $last_insert_id,
            'gambar'    => $tambahan,
        );
        $this->db->insert('produk_image', $data_gambar);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: You can only use the live Code Snippet feature for client-side JavaScript/HTML/CSS, which should be obvious as per the corresponding labels on each panel.

Comment: when you are calling model you have used $this->produk_adm->add($data, $gambar, $tambahan);

Answer (score 2):

```
$filesCount = count($_FILES['photo_gallery']['name']);    
for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                    $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name'] = $_FILES['photo_gallery']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['type'] = $_FILES['photo_gallery']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['photo_gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['error'] = $_FILES['photo_gallery']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['size'] = $_FILES['photo_gallery']['size'][$i];
                    $file_name=$this->crud->upload_file('gambar_tambah',$upload_image_path);
                    $image_data[$i]['image'] = $file_name;
                    $this->crud->add('table_name',$image_data[$i]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use same id name twice. The id value must be unique for every field. Your code for upload is wrong you are assigning value of 
 `$_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name']= $files['gambar_tambah']['name'][$i];`
You can't do this insted you just assign value to a variable like 
`$image_name = $_FILES['gambar_tambah']['name'];`
and insert that into database every time when loop runs or make array of it and insert it into one filed by implode function.

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling model you have used three parameters and in model you are using one.

use

```
 $this->load->model('produk/adm');
 $this->produk_adm->add($tambahan);
```

instead of

```
$this->produk_adm->add($data, $gambar, $tambahan);
```

and in model

```
 function add($tambahan){
    $last_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $data_gambar = array(
        'id_produk' => $last_insert_id, // if it is auto increment in db, remove this line
        'gambar'    => $tambahan,
    );
    $this->db->insert('produk_image', $data_gambar);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```